# Saben como obtener el valor de un select que esta dentro de una tabla

Tags: html, jquery, select

Tengo este codigo que me genera un select dentro de una tabla por que se llena de acuerdo a una base de datos y el select tiene un limite de acuerdo a su fila, cuando hago click en confirmar quisiera sacar los valores que el usuario ha seleccionado, de cada fila un valor. ¿Como podria hacerlo?

[image: La tabla de datos]

```
function Pedir()
{
  console.log(localStorage.ped);
   $.ajax({
       headers:{'Authorization':'bearer '+localStorage.authentication},
       type: "GET",
       url: "http://localhost:8008/api/v1/product/"+localStorage.ped+"/product",
       contentType: 'application/json',
       success: function (response) {
           let vacio = `<tr><td colspan="4">SIN REGISTROS</td></tr>`;
           if(response.length > 0)
           {
               let filas = ``;
               $.each(response,function(i, item){
                 console.log(i);
                 var new_select = '<select name="" id="">'
                 for (var i = 0; i <= item.quantity; i++) {
                   new_select += '<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>'
                 }
                  new_select += '</select>'
                   filas += `<tr><td>${item.pelicula}</td><td>${item.quantity}</td><td>
                   ${new_select}
                   </td></tr>`;
                   console.log(item);
               });
               $('#contenedor').html(filas)
           }
           else{
               $('#contenedor').html(vacio)
           }
       },
       error: function(){
           Refresh();
       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Podrías ponerle a todos los `<select>` la misma clase. Entonces tan solo te haría falta iterarlos para ir sacando el valor de cada uno y hacer con ellos lo que necesites.

```js
$(function () {
  $('#confirmar').on('click', recuperar_selects);
});

function recuperar_selects () {
  let selects = $('.mi-select');
  
  selects.each(function () {
    let select = $(this);
    console.log(select.val());
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Pepe</td>
    <td>18 años</td>
    <td>
      <select class="mi-select">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Maria</td>
    <td>21 años</td>
    <td>
      <select class="mi-select">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pedro</td>
    <td>40 años</td>
    <td>
      <select class="mi-select">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="confirmar" type="button">Confirmar</button>
```

Comment: Si, lo que pasa es que cuando llamo la tabla desde el Html no puedo Limitar su valor de acuerdo a los resultados de la base de datos, por eso creo el select en el Jquery.

Comment: No entiendo el problema. Sería añadirle la clase al select cuando lo creas dinamicamente desde **JQuery**. Al propio HTML que construyes en la función que nos muestras.

Comment: En el Html solo llamó a la tabla y si coloco select (New select) en el Html, no lo encuentra es como si estuviera vacío y no captura ningún valor.